# I have filtered my Excel data and now I want to number the rows. How do I do that?

Tags: excel, filtering

Basically all I want to do is to insert a new column after having filtered my data by a certain criterion, and then insert consecutive numbers into that column, one for each row. I.e., I have data like this in one column:

> Armstrong, John
>
> Beattie, Jane
>
> Coombs, John

And I want a new column running next to it so it looks like:

> 1   Armstrong, John
>
> 2   Beattie, Jane
>
> 3   Coombs, John

I have tried inputting the first few numbers and then dragging down to fill the rest of the column but when I do that all of the numbers turn to 1 for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

Try this function:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3, B$2:B2)
```

You can find more details in this [blog entry](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/03/19/number-the-visible-rows-in-excel-autofilter/).

Answer (score 5):

Okay I found the correct answer to this issue [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/how-to-auto-fill-in-sequence-numbering-on-a/3df380eb-3567-4c46-a57e-b8c41fb8f92a)

Here are the steps:

1. Filter your data.
2. Select the cells you want to add the numbering to.
3. Press F5.
4. Select Special.
5. Choose "Visible Cells Only" and press OK.
6. Now in the top row of your filtered data (just below the header) enter the following code:

   =MAX($"Your Column Letter"$1:"Your Column Letter"$"The current row for the filter - 1") + 1

   Ex:

   =MAX($A$1:A26)+1

   Which would be applied starting at cell A27.
7. Hold Ctrl and press enter.

Note this only works in a range, not in a table!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm no expert but this is the solution we used:
Before you filter your data, first create a temporary column to populate your entire data set with your original sort order. Auto number the temporary "original sort order" column.  Now filter your data. Copy and paste the filtered data into a new worksheet.  This will move only the filtered data to the new sheet so that your row numbers will become consecutive.  Now auto number your desired field.  Go back to your original worksheet and delete the filtered rows.  Copy and paste the newly numbered data from the secondary sheet onto the bottom of your original worksheet.  Then clear your filter and sort the worksheet by the temporary "original sort order" column. This will put your newly numbered data back into its original order and you can then delete the temporary column.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a column** for example 'Selected' First.
Then **Filter your data**.
Go to the column 'Selected'. Provide **any proxy text or number to all rows**. like '1' or 'A' - **now your hidden Rows are Blank**
Now, **Clear Filter** and Use **Sorting - two levels**
Sort by - 'Selected' Ascending - this leaves blank cells at bottom 
Add Sort Level - 'Any column you Desire' your order

Now, Why dont you **drag the autofill** yourself.

Oops, I have no reputation here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need to fill up a column with a sequence series for each value on another column. I tried all the answers above and could not fix the problem. I solved it with a simple VBA macro.

My data have the same structure (but with 3000 rows):

- N2 is the column on which the table is filtered;
- N3 is the column where I wanted to fill a series;

### A | B

### N2 | N3

### 1 | 1

### 2 | 1

### 3 | 1

### 1 | 2

### 6 | 1

### 4 | 1

### 2 | 2

### 1 | 3

### 5 | 1

Here below the code:

```
> Sub Seq_N3() ' ' Seq_N3 Macro ' Sequence numbering of N3 based on N2 value
> do N2 
>     Dim N2 As Integer
>     Dim seq As Integer
> 
>         With ActiveSheet
>             
>             For N2 = 1 To 7 Step 1
>             seq = 1                 ' 
>             .Range("B2").Select     ' 
>             
>                 Do While ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value2 <> 0
>                     
>                     If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = N2 Then        
>                         ActiveCell.Value2 = seq                         
>                         seq = seq + 1                                   
>                         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
>                     Else
>                         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select                  
>                     End If
>                     
>                 Loop
>                 
>             Next N2
>                    
>         End With End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Highlight the entire column (not including the header) of the column you wish to populate

Step 2: (Using Kutools) On the Insert dropdown, click "Fill Custom List"

Step 3: Click Edit

Step 4: Create your list (For Ex: 1, 2)

Step 5: Choose your new custom list and then click "Fill Range"

DONE!!!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way do this is to remove filter, fill series from top of total data. Filter your desired data back in, copy list of numbers into a new sheet (this should be only the total lines you want to add numbering to) paste into column A1. Add "1" into column B1, right click and hold then drag down to end of numbers and choose "fill series". Now return to your list with filters and in the next column to the right "VLOOKUP" the filtered number against the list you pasted into a new sheet and return the 2nd value.

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be using formula **=Row()-Row(ColumnHeaderCell)** then Apply it to the whole Column [But this not works in filter row number]

Answer (score 0):

Although the methods described in this thread allow sequential numbers to be added to visible cells in a filtered range, the formulas for doing so are likely to break if the cells currently hidden by the filter have existing values. Ideally, you would just copy the filtered range after adding formulas to number them--but you will get a "no can do" message because of the breaks in the selected range. The workaround is to use a currently blank auxiliary column.

The instructions that follow (taken from my answer in an Experts Exchange thread) assume that a filtered range (cells B5:B7147) needs new sequential numbers starting with cell B116.

The overall approach uses F5...Special Cells to select just the cells we care about at the moment. And we will be using an auxiliary column to store intermediate values.

The starting point is with filter applied, and you want to update the numbers in column B starting with cell B116. We will use column K as the auxiliary column. And we note that the data extends through row 7147.

Put 9918 (the next sequential number) in cell K116. Then select the range of cells from K117 to K7147. Now use F5...Special Cells...Visible cells ribbon item to select just the cells in column K that need new sequential numbers. Click in the formula bar and type the formula shown below. Hold the Control key down and hit Enter to put sequential numbers in the visible cells.

```
`=MAX(K$116:K116)+1`
```

Now clear the AutoFilter. In the address bar (just above the intersection of row numbers and column letters), type K5:K7147 and hit Enter. This will instantly select those cells without need to drag the cursor down through thousands of rows.

Next, use F5...Special Cells...Blanks to select the blank cells in column K. In cell K5 Control + Enter the formula shown below.

`=IF(B5="","",B5)`

Use the trick with the address bar to select K5:K7147. Copy those cells. Next, use the address bar trick to select B5:B7147. Now do a Paste Special...Values. You now have the desired numbers in column B without formulas and without any of the originally hidden values being overwritten.

Finally, you may clear (or delete) the auxiliary column K.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

On first row set value 1 (e.g cell `A1`)

on next row set: `=A1+1`

Finally autocomplete the remaining rows

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. It works until inputting the formula, but when you drag the box for the autocomplete everything turns to 1.

Comment: Drag from 2nd row not the 1st (from =A1+1)

Comment: I am dragging from 2nd row. Still turning everything to 1.

Comment: I assume that 1st cell is A1 if not (e.g it is F3) the snippet in 2nd row should be =F3+1 ...e.t.c

Comment: The first cell is B12. I've put 1 in B12. Then in the next cell down, which happens to be B13, I put in the formula '=B12+1' and it came out as 2. Then when I select B13 and drag down, every cell reads on. But the next cell after B13 is actually B31 due to my filter being applied, so that might matter.